# Override the admin template

Tags: module, magento-1, adminhtml, magento-enterprise

I am trying to override the `order_items` admin template in Magento with my custom module but it's working.
Layout file educertification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view> 
        <reference name="order_items"> 
            <action method="addColumnRender">
                <column>name</column>
                <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
                <template>educertification/sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnRender">
                <column>name</column>
                <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name_grouped</block>
                <template>educertification/sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
                <type>grouped</type>
            </action>
        </reference> 
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

I have created new template file with template directory educertification/sales/items/column/name.phtml

My config.xml of module

```
<adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <educertification>
                    <file>educertification.xml</file>
                </educertification>
            </updates>
        </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

but it's not working. Please help

Comment: Where is your layout.xml located? Did you change the admin theme? Make sure your layout.xml/layout handle is processed after the one you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your approach and everything is working fine. Make sure that:

1. Your module's layout file is in `adminhtml/default/default/layout/educertification.xml`
2. Your template file is located in `adminhtml/default/default/template/educertification/sales/items/column/name.phtml`
3. After that you could try to clear the cache.