# Override order item view phtml in Admin Section

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, adminhtml, overrides, sales-order

I need to rewrite the code for sales/order item view in Admin which is located in here:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
```

i need to completely rewrite the phtml code, is there a way to this?

what i've done so far:

phtml location:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/namespace/module/name.phtml
```

layout location:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/namespace/module/module.xml
```

layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
  <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
      <reference name="order_items">
          <action method="addColumnRender">
              <column>name</column>
              <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
              <template>namespace/module/name.phtml</template>
          </action>
          <action method="addColumnRender">
              <column>name</column>
              <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name_grouped</block>
              <template>namespace/module/name.phtml</template>
              <type>grouped</type>
          </action>
      </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87035/override-the-admin-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml` file by below code.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_items">
        <action method="addColumnRender">
            <column>name</column>
            <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
            <template>PATH_TO_YOUR_PHTML_FILE</template>
        </action>
        <action method="addColumnRender">
            <column>name</column>
            <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name_grouped</block>
            <template>PATH_TO_YOUR_PHTML_FILE</template>
            <type>grouped</type>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Add above code to your layout xml file.

Comment: where should i put my phtml file? in extension or custom theme? can you explain it by detail step by step?

Comment: If you have a module ready then create your template file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/yourmodulename/name.phtml` and put this path to `PATH_TO_YOUR_PHTML_FILE` in xml file. Refer to sohel's comment for more reference.

Comment: its not working, see my updated question

Comment: @simpleguy, Please add your `config.xml` code to the question.

Comment: oh yeah i forgot to add to config.xml , now it's working thanks